# Sum of Pascal's Triangle rows

Tags: python, algorithm, pascals-triangle

I implemented an algorithm for finding sums of Pascal's Triangle rows, but it's slowly for the contest. My program passed 4 test cases, but failed in the next case with a runtime error. Can I make my code faster?

```
import math

n = int(input())

for i in range(n):
    print int(math.pow(2, (int(input())-1)))
```

Input Format is the first line contains the number of test cases T. Then T test cases follow:

```
2
1
3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Math.pow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/math.html#math.pow) works with floats, so solution may be inexact for large exponent. Moreover, for values over 1023, it throws `OverflowError`.

Use `x ** y` operator instead, or builtin [`pow`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#pow) function.

Comment: wow, thank you, I passed one test case more, but I have runtime errors 'Terminated due to timeout' as before -(.

Comment: Then you should implement some [fast exponentiation method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring), keeping all intermediate results to answer next test cases efficiently. I think 2k-ary method is a good fit.